# It is possible to use Grpc.AspNetCore in C# console application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

I wannt to implement the grpc server in a C# / .NET Core console application rather than an ASP.NET Core web application and I have no idea how to do it or if it is even possible.

I did successfully implemented the client C# console app with grpc.net client and the server in ASP.NET Core app using `grpc.aspnetcore`, but could not figure out how to implement grpc server using `grpc.aspnetcore` in a C# console app

Comment: Yeah... You can run kestrel in console app... Basically grpc needs http server to run... You may run it fx inside iis but you can also run it as standalone executable with kestrel

Answer (score 0):

For hosting app to an IP address you need the sdk `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` to use `WebApplication.CreateBuilder`.

Actually asp.net core app (using web sdk to host to ip) can be modified from a console app (cannot host to ip) by changing the sdk, so it doesn't really make a difference.

Follow this tutorial you get a gRPC server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio.
Now you create a console app, then double click the project name to open .csproj file. Change the `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` . Then rebuild the solution, then you could using the exactly same code as the tutorial to build a grpc server in this "console app". (Actually it can be called an asp.net core app now)